# Add column on Mysql using store procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a store procedure to add a column on a table.
when i use this code(like below),I want to create a column with name like 'newColumn' that I can name when I call  procedure. But when I call procedure the column added but not with my name newColumn but with column name x!! 
Thank you.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addColumn(x varchar(20))
BEGIN
alter table proc
add column x varchar(20) not null;
END //
DELIMITER ;

call addColumn('newColumn');
```

Comment: You can't use the parameters like that; you'd need to construct the alter query dynamically as a string and prepare-execute it. _... and this kind of (dynamic structural changes) is usually a bad idea._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the query using concat of the various parts and execute it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addColumn(x varchar(20))
BEGIN
    SET @STMT = CONCAT("alter table proc add column ", x, " varchar(20) not null");
    PREPARE S FROM @STMT;
    EXECUTE S;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE S;
END
```

But as mentioned in comments, this is **dangerous** - it can lead to SQL Injection attacks and other problems. At the very least, please sanitize `x` as much as possible.